# Get subdomain in .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess content:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.*(.+) 

RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_uri=/$1&_subdomain=%1&_host=%3 [QSA,L]
```

I want to get `subdomain` of the url(if it exists), but when I add a quantifier to `\.`, the result of `_subdomain` is **example.localhost** instead of **example**. 
The full url is **example.localhost**. 
Anyone can explain to me?

Comment: "Full url is `example.localhost`" - but what about the live site? `subdomain.example.com`?

Comment: Now It's just in development and testing, I'll handle for a live site after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `^(.*)\.(.+)`

Your current regex is making the `.` optional, while it should be required exactly once. Since `\.*` matches 0 or more times, therefore the greedy matching of `^(.*)` is capturing everything up to the last character that is matched by `(.+)`

Comment: But I want (.*) and (\.) is optional. Is there a way to capture it as optional and also save the content of (.*) to _subdomain below?

Comment: So what you need is: capture everything if string does not contain a `.`, otherwise capture everything until the `.`?

Comment: yes, capture everything until the `.` . I've figured out how the `(.*)` greedy, then I replace the pattern to `^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)\.*(.+)` and it works. thank you for such a helpful explaination.